# Analysis approach: time-series or multiple models?

Tags: regression, time-series, hypothesis-testing

I have data which (I think) does not warrant a time series analysis, but I am note sure whether my alternative analysis approach is acceptable:

The data consists of a numerical and a categorical predictor at time-point 0 and a predictand at time-point 0, 1, and 2. I want to test whether there is a relation (especially an interaction between the predictors) for the development of the predictand (predicted decline over time).

In a time series model this would generally look like this
$$y_t=X_t β + u_t$$
but in my case like this
$$y_t=X_0 β + u_t$$

My alternative approach would be to have three separate models, one for each time-point and somehow compare them. However, this does not feel right to me.

Any comments or suggestions on how to approach this analysis?

Edit:
Data example:

```
mydata <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="
  yt0   yt1   yt2   cond    xt0
  10    9     8     b       7
  12    12    11    a       3
  8     5     2     c       12
")
```

cond is factorial, x and y are numerical. 1 Case per condition just as example, in reality, I have 3 conditions with ~70-80 cases each.

P.S. It would be nice to use something that would be able to handle missing data in $y_t$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if understand it correctly,
If you have data points for all your data in form of a categorical measurement:
time point 0, 1, 2 Then it is possible to compare all three groups and make three separated models on a variable.

Can you post your data? It is possible to do time series with dummy time series points which results in time series cross sectional data or time series panel data:

See the second post on research gate:
[researchgate](https://www.researchgate.net/post/What-is-difference-between-cross-sectional-data-and-panel-data)

From what you are describing these approaches seem possible

----------------------------UPDATE------------------------------

I'm sorry I needed a bit of time to think about it. And I have to revise my assumptions.

So you have three dependent variables `y0, y1, y2` that are the same variable but at different time points. You have only one factor variable and a metric exogenous variable `x0`. If you would made three models for every `y` that would result in the same `x0` for every y variable you have. That is the same as copying your variable x0 three times for the length of `y1` and `y2`.

The fundamental question is: what is `x0`? is it ok, that there are no values for `x1` and `x2` that could be observed? or can `x0` be assumed as equal as in the period of `y1` and `y2`. Two examples:

Imagine `y0` is the year 2000 and you have several points for `y0` which reflect the days. If `x0` is the temprature on a certain day during a hot season then it could be ok to assume the same value of `x0` to `x1` and `x2` at these days at time period 0.

```
    row      amount of bees flying at time0           temperature
day1-2000                12                                19
day2-2000                12                                20
day3-2000                13                                21
day1-2001                11                                NA (but in case of three models we expect 19)
```

Then it could be possible to assume a similar `x1` and `x2` thus resulting in three models.

But how do you argue the decline? if you think `x0` is something that should have a declining or bad outcome on y which was only active in `y0` and should be still has an effect on y, then you have to consider transforming your variable with a reasonable carryover effect.

```
e.g. media example (with end of year 2000)
        row      sales due to media impact               media budget
    day29-2000                12                                40
    day30-2000                12                                50
    day31-2000                13                                21
    day01-2001                11                                 0 + (21*50% carryover which results in 10.5
```

In summary to give you a final advise: I would not model anything, I would look for a curvefitting approach in R. I think it would be possible to format your data to one `y` and transform your `x` with a certain amount of carryover and add the factor as another parameter in an assumed model function, which can be searched by the fitting function, that describes a declining or expiring effect. E.g. an exponential or linear decay https://www.thoughtco.com/exponential-decay-definition-2312215 and to find that effect, you could assume such a negative decay, thus the model function. The final curve fitting in R should give you a fittied function and thus R², residuals, all you want. The fundamental difference is, that you assume a model decay function in advance and let R find the fit and the decay. to your declining. And you wont have problems with transforming your missing variables in `x0`, as they will be transformed with an carryover effect.

What you should do is assume a decay function and let R fit it with your data by putting all ys into one column. The decay effect of x in your model will be estimated by the R curve fitting.

The required packages to try curvefitting in R are:
nlsr with the nlxb function:https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/nlsr/versions/2019.9.7/topics/nlxb

and nls2 with the nls2 function:
https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/nls2/versions/0.2/topics/nls2

At the end of the curve fitting you get the desired decay parameters to describe your decline to the function you chosed. However you have to calculate R² manual

If you wish more information on that topic, just ask me. But I think we are on the right way. I can even give you a code example of a nlxb curve fitting.

Comment: thanks for the input, I added some sample data.

Comment: I updated my post, please dont be afraid of the length, its a lot to discuss and assume. But I'm eager to help.

Comment: thank you for you input, it is very much appreciated! It is ok to carry over $x_0$, although it alters interpretation (but in a way that is actually closer to my hypthesis). I think however, I will settle with a mixed ANOVA with a single $y$ and time-point as within factor, the rest as between factors/covariates. If I understand your approach correctly, this is not too different to your suggestion, regarding the data transformation, but with a different analysis (although glm is also just curvefitting, as far as i understand it). I am going to accept your answer nonetheless .

Comment: yes curve fitting is some way of glm, but you can insert any formula you want. Then go with the ANOVA, I would be happy if you could post your results afterwards. Im interested in the outcome!